# can't access dead object, imacros

Tags: imacros

Im getting the following error with imacros

```
  URL GOTO=http://www.tblog.com/blog_admin/addpost.php?view=full
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:post_form ATTR=NAME:ititle CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:mce_editor_0_code
TAB T=2
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:source ATTR=ID:htmlSource CONTENT={{!VAR8}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:source ATTR=ID:insert
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:post_form ATTR=NAME:publish&&VALUE:Publish<SP>This<SP>Post!
```

TypeError: can't access dead object, line: 9 (Error code: -1001)

If somebody can help here are some logging details
account:lugartecnologico52
paswword:1234

The site is tblog.com

Answer (score 1):

We need to open a blank tab to address this error.
 steps to follow

1. Open a tab
2. Add these commands
   Tab T=2
   Tab T=1
3. Run the macro

Let me know in case of any queries